# Get check box values inside array for use in posting form data

Tags: php, functions, array, variables

So I have the following function with an array of variables that handles a profile form.
All but one is a typical input with the exception of `'member-comptency[]'`. It's a select field field with several possible values. Right now, the form saves, all the data comes through as expected with the exception of that field which simply returns a number.

I've tried in vain several times to modify this in different ways, but only produces a 'no-save' situation, or further non-descrip errors. I understand this field is an array itself, but not sure how to even ask google the right questions to get myself on track.

Any help would certainly be appreciated!

```
function getUMFormData(){
    $id = um_user('ID');
        $names = array(
            'member-company',
            'member-phone',
            'member-website',
            'member-competency[]',
            'member-contact-billing-name'
        );

        foreach( $names as $name )
        update_user_meta( $id, $name, $_POST[$name] );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a WordPress-specific question, and without seeing your form code it's hard to say, but what is obviously wrong is that you are referring to the variable with the `[]` in the name.  Try removing them and test again.  If not, I suggest var_dumping the `$_POST` variable and seeing what it contains and working from there.